# Динамически вызвать обобщенный метод

Tags: c#

Есть функция:

```
static void getTable<T>(){}
```

Хочу вызвать так:

```
getTable<Type.GetType("MyClass")>();
```

Возможно ли?

Comment: Это очень странный метод — он ничего не принимает и ничего не возвращает. Скорее всего можно просто сделать версию этого метода с сигнатурой `void getTable(Type type)`

Comment: неужто ни один из ответов не подошел?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй как-то так сделать:

```
GetType().GetMethod("getTable").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyClass))?.Invoke();
```

Но это на крайний случай если невозможно сделать через наследование.

---

Если же возможно сделать наследование, то передавай интерфейс или родительский класс.

```
    static void getTable<IBaseInterfase>(){}
```

и тогда ты можешь вызывать нужный метод внутри getTable который прописан в родителе. Ну и, конечно же, передавать любой дочерний класс внутрь Base

Answer (score 1):

Сколько я насмотрелся на мучения с подобными вызовами... Динамика и рефлексия только усложняют и замедляют код.

Сколько у вас типов, с которым может вызываться этот метод? Думаю, всего несколько штук. Вряд ли более десятка. Так напишите просто:

```
if (Type.GetType(typeName) == typeof(MyClass))
{
    getTable<MyClass>();
}
else if (Type.GetType(typeName) == typeof(OtherClass))
{
    getTable<OtherClass>();
}
else if ...
```

Просто, понятно, работает быстро.

Comment: "Просто, понятно, работает быстро.".... а еще требует поддержки. При добавлении класса нужно возвращатся сюда и дописывать код. Но да, такой подход тоже имеет место быть.

Comment: @Andrew - да, согласен, этот способ требует поддержки.