# Рефлексия. Как вызвать generic метод через рефлескию

Tags: c#, .net, generics, рефлексия

Проблема: есть (допустим) некий метод Foo:

```
public static T Foo<T>(string str)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T)); // пример (тело метода не важно)
}
```

Я могу его вызвать с помощью рефлексии:

```
MethodInfo foo = type.GetMethod("Foo"); // type - тип, где находится метод Foo
MethodInfo genericFoo = foo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string)); // например string
string result = genericFoo.Invoke(null, /* params... */);
```

Но дело в том, что у 1-го (и единственного) параметра метода `MakeGenericMethod` есть "приписка" `params`, что не позволяет мне вызвать метод `MakeGenericMethod` "вставив" в него массив типов :

```
public static object Bar(Type[] types, MethodInfo foo, object param)
{
    MethodInfo genericFoo = foo.MakeGenericMethod(types); // <- это не работает
    return genericFoo.Invoke(null, new object[] { param });
}
```

Как мне обогнуть это ограничение? Есть ли альтернатива `MakeGenericMethod`?

Comment: Что значит вставить массив типов? Отправляйте в метод `object[] myarray ` и все дела

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамически вызвать обобщенный метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941687/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: @Andrew Дело в том, что типы в массиве `types` (метод `Bar`) не известны, т. е. могут быть любыми и проверять каждый тип запаристо (очень). А 1-й ответ в контексте моего приложения меня никак не устраивает.

Comment: `foo.MakeGenericMethod(types) // <- это не работает` - это работает. Проверяй какие именно типы ты передаешь, и какие принимает foo

Comment: покажи как именно ты вызываешь метод `Bar`. В приведенном виде он отлично работает как есть, если поставить `;` на строке с комментарием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`MakeGenericMethod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2) принимает типы, соответствующие **generic** параметрам.

В случае с

```
public static T Foo<T>(/* params... */)
```

есть только один generic-параметр: `T`

К типам внутри круглых скобок данный метод не имеет отношения.

Для вызова полученного метода, с помощью метода `Invoke` вторым аргументом передается массив `object`, каждый элемент которого соответствует конкретному параметру в круглых скобках.

Ключевое слово `params` не меняет количество параметров, оно просто позволяет при вызове собрать нужные параметры в одну коллекцию.

Либо если передать непосредственно массив, он попадет сразу в этот параметр.

---

В отредактированном вопросе, метод `Bar`

```
public static object Bar(Type[] types, MethodInfo foo, object param)
{
    MethodInfo genericFoo = foo.MakeGenericMethod(types); // <- это работает
    return genericFoo.Invoke(null, new object[] { param });
}
```

Вполне рабочий.

Проблема может быть только в неверных параметрах, с которыми он вызывается.

Comment: Я пробовал вызвать метод через foo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {/* ... */}), но выбивало exception по типу: "Не удается скастовать тип Type[] к Type".

Comment: @СосукевичПавел, ты не туда массив вставляешь. добавь в вопрос декларацию метода, который ты хочешь вызвать, чтобы можно было на конкретном примере показать

Comment: @СосукевичПавел, Обновил ответ